# I got an error in "local variable 'current_name' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python-3.x

"Main CLI"

```
    import argparse
    
    from cloud_pricing.data.core import CloudProcessor
    
    def main():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Compare cloud pricing on the command line. Set the required compute and receive a table of compatible prices. For some services (like AWS) the instance type reflects the best fit given the input constraints.")
        parser.add_argument("--cpus", "-c", default=4, type=int,
            help="Number of CPUs to request.")
        parser.add_argument("--gpus", "-g", default=0, type=int,
            help="Number of GPUs to request.")
        parser.add_argument("--ram", "-r", default=8, type=int,
            help="Amount of RAM in Gb.")
        parser.add_argument("--gpuram", "--gr", default=10, type=int,
            help="Amount of total GPU RAM in Gb.")
        parser.add_argument("--verbose", "-v", default=False, action='store_true',
            help="Increase verbosity, showing all info columns.")
        parser.add_argument("-n", default=10, type=int,
            help="The number of results to show.")
        parser.add_argument("--unk_price", "-P", default=False, action='store_true',
            help="Exclude products that don't have a known price.")
        parser.add_argument("--out", "-o", default=None, type=str,
            help="Save the outputs to a file. {csv | json}")
        parser.add_argument("--spot", "-s", default=False, action='store_true',
            help="Use spot (preemptible) prices.")
        parser.add_argument("--update", "-U", default=False, action='store_true',
            help="Force an update to the database of prices.")
        parser.add_argument("--providers", default='ALL',
            help=("List of providers to search over. Comma separated string "
                  "of 'AWS', 'Azure', 'GCP', or 'All'. Example: 'aws,gcp' "))
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    proc = CloudProcessor(args.providers.upper())

    if args.update:
        proc.update()

    data = proc.filter(args.cpus, args.ram, args.gpus, args.gpuram, args.n, args.verbose, args.unk_price, args.spot)

    if args.out is not None:
        if args.out.endswith('csv'):
            data.to_csv(args.out)
        elif args.out.endswith('json'):
            data.to_json(args.out)
    else:
        print(data)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

I got this error. I was trying to solve this problem, but I could not.
[image]

When I run "cloud-pricing --cpus 8 --ram 32 --gpus 1 --gpuram 16", I get this massege.

Namespace(cpus=8, gpus=1, ram=32, gpuram=16, verbose=False, n=10, unk_price=False, out=None, spot=False, update=False, providers='ALL')

```
Downloading latest GCP data...

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

```html
   
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\cloud-pricing-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('cloud-pricing==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-pricing')())
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\cloud_pricing\main.py", line 35, in main
    proc = CloudProcessor(args.providers.upper())
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\cloud_pricing\data\core.py", line 22, in __init__
    self._tables.append(t())
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\cloud_pricing\data\gcp.py", line 33, in __init__
    super().__init__(table_name)
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\cloud_pricing\data\interface.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\cloud_pricing\data\gcp.py", line 156, in setup
    print(current_name)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_name' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Where is the variable "current_name' used?

Comment: @QuantumMecha This is the like of the project and "current_name" was using in gcp.py
https://github.com/Hmh4575/cloud-pricing-2.git

Comment: Please try to put the error message as a text

Answer (score 0):

In your git code https://github.com/Hmh4575/cloud-pricing-2/blob/master/cloud_pricing/data/gcp.py , You have a line 152-153 like this.

```
if i.name.lower() in {'h2', 'h3', 'h4'}:
   current_name = i.get('data-text')
```

This is the only place variable `current_name` is getting assigned. So if the `i.name` is not matching `h1/h3/h4` , there is no variable `current_name`. So the error.

You can initialize like `current_name=''` before the loop starts, and it should avoid this. Or, ensure the data matches `h1/h3/h4`

Comment: Still the error in the main.py line 35.
this is the error message:

Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'current_name' referenced before assignment

  File "C:\Users\Hakam\Desktop\cloud-pricing-master\cloud_pricing\main.py", line 35, in main
main = CloudProcessor(args.providers.upper())

  File "C:\Users\Hakam\Desktop\cloud-pricing-master\cloud_pricing\main.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()

Comment: You will have to debug and make changes to the code in the repo. The code over there seems to be bit old. Google might have made changes to their pricing pages, and the scrapper is not working probably!